# Failed to update setting 'python.analysis.typeCheckingMode'. Error: Unable to write to Folder Settings because no resource is provided

Tags: python, visual-studio, pylance

I'm trying to use jupyter notebook on VScode but I can't import pandas and other libraries and I keep getting this error too when I try to switch on "Type checking:

Failed to update setting 'python.analysis.typeCheckingMode'. Error: Unable to write to Folder Settings because no resource is provided.

[image]

Tired importing some python libraries

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Answer (score 2):

Press **Ctrl + Shift + P** to open the Command Palette in VS Code.
Search for **Settings** and click on **Open Settings** to open it.

Search for **typecheck** and under **Python > Analysis** change the dropdown to **basic** (or strict) to get rid of the error (screenshot of [typecheck for Python in Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CEEO.png)). Don't forget to **restart VS Code** after making the change.